# Rendering Filtered List in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble displaying a filtered list in my widget. It works up to the point of printing the filtered data in the list as per the query that is passed but not when that exact data needs to be displayed. I believe I will have to update the list with the filtered data every time I type in a query but I just cannot figure out how and where I need to use `setState` to update that. My code and the outputs are as follows:

Initially, the entire list gets rendered but the moment I type in a query string, the list is supposed to get modified with only the data that matched the query. This is not something that's happening at the moment. The list tends to remain as it is.

[image]

However, when I print the filtered data, it seems to work just fine(`_searchResult` printed in the `searchData` method below).

```
[
  {product_id: 8, restaurant_name: Mocambo, restaurant_id: 6, product_name: Kaju Paneer, product_description: Tasty yummy paneer gravy dish, product_image: /public/assets/product/lgml5L03-19-41.jpg, product_selling_price: 320},
  {product_id: 5, restaurant_name: City Club, restaurant_id: 1, product_name: Palak Paneer, product_description: Tasty silky gravy with goodness of palak, product_image: /public/assets/product/C6pGz101-42-17.jpg, product_selling_price: 180}, 
  {product_id: 4, restaurant_name: City Club, restaurant_id: 1, product_name: Shahi Paneer, product_description: Tasty Paneer main course dish, product_image: /public/assets/product/vgI1dR01-29-18.jpg, product_selling_price: 240}
]
```

The code:

The method that filters. (Please note that the filtering is performed after the data is fetched from the server. For my convenience, I decided to convert it into a list)

```
class PopularDishesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
 Map<String, dynamic> _dishes = {};
 final List<dynamic> _searchDish = [];
 List<dynamic> _searchResult = [];

List<dynamic> get searchDish {
    return [..._searchDish];
  }

  List<dynamic> get searchResult {
    return [..._searchResult];
  }

Future<void> searchData(String query) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + 'api/all_products');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    PopularDishes popularDishes = popularDishesFromJson(response.body);  //This method converts the response into Dart model
    _dishes = popularDishes.toJson();
    _dishes['data'].forEach((value) => _searchDish.add(value));
    _searchResult = _searchDish.where((element) {
      final name = element['product_name'].toLowerCase();
      final searchQuery = query.toLowerCase();
      return name.contains(searchQuery);
    }).toList();
    print(_searchResult);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The widget where this is supposed to be rendered:

```
class SearchState extends State<Search> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool value = true;
  String query = '';
  List<dynamic> search = [];
  PopularDishesProvider popular = PopularDishesProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {                    //This is to make the API Call for the first time
    // TODO: implement initState
    Provider.of<PopularDishesProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .searchData('');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;
    final searchProvider = Provider.of<PopularDishesProvider>(context).searchResult;

    PopularDishesProvider popular = PopularDishesProvider();

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          // backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          toolbarHeight: 100,
          title: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 40,
                .......
                .......
                .......
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    // color: Colors.red,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 2),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              margin:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6, right: 4),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                              height: 45,
                              width: width * 0.7,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(14)),
                                  border:
                                      Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2)),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                      flex: 9,
                                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: TextField(
                                          controller: _controller,
                                          onChanged: (value) async {
                                            setState(() {
                                              query = value;
                                            });
                                            await popular.searchData(value);
                                          },
                                          autofocus: true,
                                          cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            hintText:
                                                'Search By Restaurant or Food',
                                            hintStyle:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                  Flexible(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                      child: const Icon(Icons.close,
                                          color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                                title: Text(searchProvider [index]['product_name'])),
                            itemCount: searchProvider.length,
                          ),
                        )
                        )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please help out?

Comment: looks like an error with your state management, have you tried with a different approach to state management?

Comment: Nope not really. I'm open to suggestions of all sorts